# Storage for button clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a counter for button clicks, but if I **refresh** the page it sets back to `'0'`. How can I **storage** the input **value** so if I close the browser the **previous** **number** will remain still?

```js
$(function() {
  $('.counter').click(function() {
    $(this).val(parseInt($(this).val()) + 1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" class="counter" value="0">
```

Comment: You could use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: you can use AJAX to store new value to database every time a button is pressed so that you can retrieve it any time you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use local storage to store a key/value pair. Here is an example of how you could use it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

  //Firstly check if buttonClickCounter is in local storage from before.
  if(localStorage.getItem("buttonClickCounter") === null){
    //buttonClickCounter is not in local storage.

  }else{
    //buttonClickCounter is in local storage.
    var counter = localStorage.getItem("buttonClickCounter");   
    //insert the counter value into the HTML.   
    $('.counter').val(counter);     
  }


  $('.counter').click(function() {
    var newValue = parseInt($(this).val()) + 1;
    $(this).val(newValue);
    //store the new counter value in local storage.
    localStorage.setItem('buttonClickCounter', newValue);   
  });

});
```

You can check local storage values in the console under the Application tab as follows: 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can use any one of these 
local storage, 
session storage, 
cookies, 
querystring,

Answer (score 0):

You can use `localstorage` or `cookies` for this.
Take a look at these websites:
**Localstorage:** [Localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) 
**Cookies:** [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)

Example `localstorage`:

```
var buttonvalue = $('.counter').val();
localStorage.setItem("buttonvalue", buttonvalue);
// get value of button
var someVarName = localStorage.getItem("buttonvalue");
```

For cookies in Jquery you should include a library:
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Then you can use this:

```
$.cookie("buttonvalue", $('.counter').val());
var cookieValue = $.cookie("buttonvalue");
```